# Lifting a linear surface from a curve to the ambient surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex K3 surface and $C$ a smooth curve on $X$ and $A$ a basepoint free line bundle on $C$.

Aprodu's paper - Lazarsfeld Mukai bundles and applications says this. We cannot lift the linear system $|A|$ to $X$ if $Pic\,X$ is generated by $C$ or if $X$ contains no elliptic curves, for most $|A|$.

I do not understand this statement. I know that in general $A$ need not be a restriction of a line bundle from $X$. But he seems to be saying more. Any clarification of the above statement will be helpful.

Comment: I do not completely understand this statement. What if $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ is generated by a very ample line bundle $C$ and $A=\mathcal{O}_X(C)|_C$? In this case $A$ can be clearly lifted to $X$  , one lifting being  $\mathcal{O}_X(C)$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ Polizzi, of course you are correct.  Omitted from the quote OP shared is 'for most |A|" .  I think your comment pretty much explains what Aprodu is trying to say.

Comment: @aginensky, What about when he says if $X$ contains no elliptic curve. I did not understand that bit?

Comment: I have edited the question to include for most $|A|$.

Comment: @user52991 , again as in the Polizzi comment, on most K-3 surfaces, that would mean that the surface has an elliptic fibration and most K-3 surfaces aren't elliptic.

Comment: I also think that there are other restrictions on the existence of elliptic curves on K-3 surfaces, but exact theorems escape me at the moment.

Comment: @aginensky, Aprodu is sAying that the Linear system cannot be lifted if the K3 surface has no elliptic curves. An elliptic K3 surface has elliptic curves. So that is not the reason I guess.

Comment: @user52991 hence the constant use of 'most' in this conversation

Comment: @aginensky, now I think I understand. For K3 surfaces with elliptic fibration the restriction map of Picard group from $X$ to $E$ is surjective isn't it?

Comment: @user52991 No, that can never happen as K-3 is regular ! I don't want to speak to Aprodu, but the gyst of his comment should be that curves have way more special linear systems than most K-3 surfaces have.